# cannot update an object with jpa

Tags: java, jpa, variable-assignment, equals, jpql

I'm having trouble updating records as so:

```
package legacy.database;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

public class Queries {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Queries.class.getName());
    private final EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("LegacyDatabasePU");
    private final EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    public Queries() {
    }

    private List<Clients> findAll() {
        Query q = em.createQuery("select c from Clients c");
        List<Clients> clients = q.getResultList();
        return clients;
    }




    public Clients findById(int id) {
        Clients client = em.find(Clients.class, id);
        return client;
    }


    public void update(Clients c2) {
        Clients c1 = em.find(Clients.class, c2.getId());
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
        Timestamp t = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
        c2.setDateUpdated(t.toString());
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        c2.setDateUpdated(t.toString());
        c1 = c2;
        log.info(c1.getNotes());
        log.info(c2.getNotes());
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

is there a problem with assigning c1=c2?  Do I have to manually go through c1 and update each record?

Comment: Not found any update db operation using `EntityManager` like `em.merge()` !!!

Comment: @WundwinBorn: a merge is unnecessary to modify an attached entity.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes sure `merge()` op don't need for managed instance, but i means for detached instance in OP post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the entity is not registered in the `EntityManager`, possibly like your `c2`, then it will not be updated unless you use `em.persist`, `em.merge` and so on.

And `c1 = c2` is just pointing the `c1` reference to the `c2` reference.

From the comment below, what you want to do is to copy properties of `c2` to `c1`, which can be done

- statically calling each setter/getter with the help of an editor capable of column mode editing (IntelliJ, Eclipse, jEdit, etc)
- with the use of libraries like [Apache BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/); this would use reflection.

In both case, you must remember to:

- do a deep copy if this should be done; eg: if there is a `OneToMany`, you should probably duplicate the sub entities.
- don't copy field that should not (like unique constraints)

Comment: that was my concern -- I wanted to literally copy the object itself.

Comment: Have a look at `EntityManager.merge` then. Or use stuff like `org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.copyProperties(Object, Object)` or any equivalent.

Comment: ok, I'm not using spring, but `copyProperties` sounds exactly like what I'm after.

Answer (score 2):

Do the find() within a transaction, and then call your mutating methods within the transaction. Commit will then update the object automatically. Just simple movement of the begin txn gives this. Only you know what the various updates are so no attempt is made to clean that up

```
try
{
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    Clients c1 = em.find(Clients.class, c2.getId());
    Timestamp t = new Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());
    c2.setDateUpdated(t.toString());
    c1 = c2;
    log.info(c1.getNotes()); log.info(c2.getNotes());

    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
finally
{
    if (em.getTransaction().isActive())
    {
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add a code example to your answer. And please modify the update method so that it takes an ID as argument: it will make it much clearer.

Comment: what about combining delete and create to simulate an update?  when using `persist`, perhaps specify the id of the object being persisted?